# MSSQL Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Tags: sql-server

I am getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.` .from JDBC sqlserver driver. But its working fine from SQL server management studio .

```
    CREATE  VIEW REVENUE0 (SUPPLIER_NO, TOTAL_REVENUE) AS  SELECT L_SUPPKEY,    SUM(L_EXTENDEDPRICE*(1-L_DISCOUNT)) FROM    LINEITEM WHERE  L_SHIPDATE  >= '1997-05-01' AND     L_SHIPDATE  < dateadd(mm, 3, cast ('1997-05-01' as date)) GROUP BY  L_SUPPKEY 
    GO

    SELECT  S_SUPPKEY,  S_NAME,     S_ADDRESS,  S_PHONE,    TOTAL_REVENUE FROM  SUPPLIER,   REVENUE0 WHERE  S_SUPPKEY   = SUPPLIER_NO AND   TOTAL_REVENUE   = ( SELECT  MAX(TOTAL_REVENUE)
                FROM    REVENUE0
              ) ORDER   BY  S_SUPPKEY

    DROP VIEW REVENUE0
```

Comment: A `VIEW` can't contain multiple data sets. That query would fail in SSMS as well. You need create the `VIEW` in it's own batch. In SSMS that would be by using `GO`, in other applications, that might mean making 2 statement calls.

Comment: Are you really trying to create a view and query from it in a single query? If so, is a view really the right tool for the job here?

Comment: @Larnu my bad I am using `GO` in SSMS and its working there , but not from script .

Comment: No, because `GO` isn't a Transact-SQL keyword, @curiousguy. It's an IDE keyword that applications like SSMS detect and use as a Batch Separator. This is why i said *"in other applications, that might mean making 2 statement calls."*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes I am trying to create and query from view in a single Query. I am using this for some DB bench-marking.

Comment: *"I am trying to create and query from view in a single Query"* You can't, @curiousguy . A `VIEW`'s definition must be the **only** statement in the batch. You can't `CREATE`/`ALTER` a `VIEW` and return data from it in the same query. You would need 2 separate batches.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated the query

Comment: That doesn't change anything.`DROP` would still need to be in a separate batch, @curiousguy . As I stated *"A VIEW's definition must be the **only** statement in the batch."*

Comment: It looks like you should be using a CTE instead of a view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the view "dynamically"?

```
exec('create view mytest as select * from sys.objects');
select * from mytest;
drop view if exists mytest; -- or ... exec('drop view mytest');
```